# Is this an injection from $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I am wondering if $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow (0,1)$ is an injection if $f$ just moves the decimal point to the left of each number an equal amount of times as how far the decimal point is from the right of the first digit of the real number which has the decimal point featured to the furthest point right from its first digit, adding a $0$ every time we move the decimal point left and there's nothing there: e.g. if we had $3.14, 314.1, 34567.2$ which $f$ was mapping from, $f$ would output $0.0000314, 0.00314,$ and $0.34567$ respectively.

I am unsure because I don't know whether there is a well defined number which constitutes the greatest number of spots to the right which the decimal point is featured in a real number. If this isn't an injection, is there a way to use a similar idea to define an injection from $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $(0,1)$?

Comment: What's $f({1\over 3})$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber would this not just convert $1 \over 3$ to its decimal expansion, and then move the decimal point to the left the appropriate amount of times?

Comment: I don't understand the definition of $f$.  It seems to only be defined for terminating decimals.  I have no guess how to define $f\left(\frac 13\right)$, for instance. If you think it's clear, what is the value?

Comment: @Shmuel Remember that ${1\over 3}=0.333333...$

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes, is there is a reason why terminating decimals are necessary to define $f$? the greatest number of spots a real number has the decimal to the right of its first digit seems to depend only on the things to the left of the decimal, not the things to the right of it, so I am not sure how a non-terminating decimal affects $f$

Comment: @Shmuel OK, so then what is $f({1\over 3})$? It's possible I'm misunderstanding your idea; I'll be honest, your description " moves the decimal point to the left of each number an equal amount of times as how far the decimal point is from the right of the first digit of the real number which has the decimal point featured to the furthest point right from its first digit" is not very clear to me.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I agree; the description makes very little sense.

Comment: I think you should edit your question @Shmuel. As others have pointed out, it is unclear exactly how you have defined $f$, which makes it hard to answer your question.

Comment: The fact that you can't simply tell us what $f\left(\frac 13\right)$ is suggests that you don't understand your definition either.  Frankly, your description is extremely hard to follow.

Comment: Or, the answer is "no, this is not an injective function from $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $(0,1)$ because it is not a function with domain $\mathbb{R}_+$ at all".

Comment: @NoahSchweber it would be of the form $0.0000000000 \ldots 33333333 \ldots$ where there amount of zeroes preceding the first $3$ is some infinite number- I myself cannot give a precise number, which is why I am asking my question. The amount of zeroes is simply how much the decimal is to the right in a specific real number, which real number has the decimal point moved the furthest point to the right. I had this idea because if I just moved the decimal point to the left of every real number to make the real number within $(0,1)$ then I would get repeats, as $3.14$ and $31.4$ would be the same

Comment: Then indeed, $f \left(\frac{1}{3} \right)$ is not well-defined, so $f: (0, \infty) \to (0, 1)$ is not well-defined.

Comment: "An infinite number of zeros followed by an infinite number of threes" is not a sequence of digits, if it means anything at all. Remember that decimal notation actually means sums like $3.14 = 3 \cdot 10^0 + 1 \cdot 10^{-1} + 4 \cdot 10^{-2}$. You can't have the first term in this sum be $3 \cdot 10^{-\infty}$ - if that's a defined real number at all, it equals zero.

Comment: @Shmuel you cannot have a decimal with an infinite number of $0$'s preceding other digits.  A decimal expansion is a sequence of digits, meaning each digit is a finite number of places to the left or right of the decimal.  If you allowed expansions such as you propose it would violate the archimedean property of the real numbers.

Comment: @M W I meant, rather, the amount of zeroes to be an arbitrarily large finite number, rather than infinite. It is simply how many digits are in the "greatest" natural number.

Comment: @Shmuel That is *precisely* the problem - there is no "greatest" natural number to speak of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposal is rather unclear, but per your comments it **does not** give a function with codomain $\mathbb{R}$ at all; this is because things like

> [a sequence] of the form 0.0000000000…33333333… where [the] amount of zeroes preceding the first 3 is some infinite number

is not actually (a valid representation of) a real number in the first place.

---

However, you may be interested to know that something similar to your idea **does** actually work! Specifically, letting $d(\alpha)$ be the number of digits in the integer part of $\alpha$ (so e.g. $d(\pi)=1$ and $d(12.3)=2$), the function $$g:\alpha\mapsto \alpha\cdot 10^{-2d(\alpha)}$$ gives an injection from $\mathbb{R}_{>1}$ to $(0,1)$. Some example values include:

- $g(31.234)=0.0031234$.
- $g(3.3333...)=g({10\over 3})=0.0333333...={1\over 30}$.
- $g(103)=0.000103$.

The injectivity of $g$ comes from the fact that we can "read off" of $g(\alpha)$ the size of the integer part of $\alpha$, by looking at the number of zeroes in the decimal expansion (a bit of care is needed here around numbers with two decimal expansions, so I'm leaving the detailed proof of injectivity as an exercise).

Note that there's a crucial asymmetry here: the "left-of-decimal-point part" of a real number **is** required to be finite. This is why the above actually results in something well-defined, while your proposal runs into trouble with things like $1\over 3$.